# How can I log in using Google OAuth in the TikTok in-app browser?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-signin

When attempting to log in with Google OAuth via the TikTok in-app browser it says "Authorization Error  Error 403 disallowed_useragent Google can't sign you in safely inside this app.  You can use Google sign-in by visiting this app's website in a browser like Safari or Chrome."

Thinking this is either a call by Google to prevent login within TikTok or they simply haven't added this user agent yet.

Answer (score 3):

Google OAuth does not work in embedded web views per policy. See https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html.

You should reach out to the app developer to recommend they use one of the alternatives recommended like Chrome Custom Tabs.

Comment: Okay, raised a bug with TikTok.  I'll comment back here if they reply.

Comment: @Ponny, any news? Bumped into same issue recently =(